# Input field sets the decimal numbers to 0?

Tags: php

I have multiple input fields in my page but 2 of these don't remember the numbers after the comma. When i fill in 34,71 and press the save button it becomes 34,0. This exact problem happens with both of the input fields.

Code of the 2 input fields:

```
<tr><td>Btw tarief: </td><td>        <input type="text" name="tarief_btw" id="tarief_btw" value="<? $tarief_btw = $tarief_btw*100; $tarief_btw=number_format($tarief_btw, 1, ',', ''); echo $tarief_btw ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Btw goed doel:</td><td> <input type="text" name="goed_doel_btw" id="goed_doel_btw" value="<? $goede_doel_btw = $goede_doel_btw*100; $goede_doel_btw=number_format($goede_doel_btw,1,',', ''); echo $tarief_btw ?>"></td></tr>
```

All Code:

```
<?php

require_once('inc/head.php');
 ?>
<div id="post-931" class="post-931 page type-page status-publish hentry">


<?php if(isset($_SESSION['hash']) && isset($_SESSION['right_groups']) &&      $_SESSION['right_groups'][1] == null ){
$social_wrapper = new SocialModuleWrapper();

if($_POST)
{
    //applies any updates to the fees, taxes and charity name
    $social_wrapper->updateGroupPost($main_group_id, array(
        'body' => stripslashes($_POST['tarief'])
    ), $tarief_id);
    $social_wrapper->updateGroupPost($main_group_id, array(
        'body' => stripslashes(($_POST['tarief_btw']/100))
    ), $tarief_btw_id);
    $social_wrapper->updateGroupPost($main_group_id, array(
        'body' => stripslashes(($_POST['goed_doel_btw']/100))
    ), $goede_doel_btw_id);
    $social_wrapper->updateGroupPost($main_group_id, array(
        'body' => stripslashes(($_POST['goed_doel']))
    ), $goed_doel_id);

    echo"<h1>Wijzigingen opgeslagen</h1>";
}




//gets the fee, taxes and charity name
$tarief = $social_wrapper->getGroupPost(1,$tarief_id);
$tarief = $tarief['body'];
$tarief_btw = $social_wrapper->getGroupPost(1,$tarief_btw_id);
$tarief_btw = $tarief_btw['body'];
$goede_doel_btw = $social_wrapper->getGroupPost(1,$goede_doel_btw_id);
$goede_doel_btw = $goede_doel_btw['body'];
$goed_doel = $social_wrapper->getGroupPost(1,$goed_doel_id);
$goed_doel = $goed_doel['body'];






        //creates the view to edit fee, taxes and charity name?>

    <div class="entry-content" style="height:300px;">
        <div id="simplr-form">
            <form action="/tarieven.php" method="post">
        <h1>Tarieven</h1>
        <table id="Tarief">

<tr><td>Tarief Commercial Area:</td><td> <input type="text" name="tarief" id="tarief" value="<?=$tarief?>"></td>  </tr>
<tr><td>Btw tarief: </td><td>        <input type="text" name="tarief_btw" id="tarief_btw" value="<? $tarief_btw = $tarief_btw*100; $tarief_btw=number_format($tarief_btw, 1, ',', ''); echo $tarief_btw ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Btw goed doel:</td><td> <input type="text" name="goed_doel_btw" id="goed_doel_btw" value="<? $goede_doel_btw = $goede_doel_btw*100; $goede_doel_btw=number_format($goede_doel_btw,1,',', ''); echo $tarief_btw ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Goede doel van de maand:</td><td> <textarea rows="4" name="goed_doel" id="goed_doel"><?=$goed_doel?></textarea></td></tr>

        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit-reg" value="Opslaan" class="submit button">
</form>
    </div></div></div>

    <?
require('inc/footer.php');
}else{
?></div> <?
require('404.php');
}
```

Comment: change your number formatting from 1 place to 2. `number_format($tarief_btw, 2, ',', '')`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use european representations for numbers. PHP doesn't know that `34,71` is really `34.71`. It'll treat it like a string, convert it to a number by its own int->string conversion rules, and your text is effectively going to be:

```
$foo = $value_from_form / 100;
becomes
$foo = '34,71' / 100;
becomes
$foo = '34' / 100;
becomes
$foo = 34 / 100;

= 0.34
```

Either mangle your string to convert `34,71` into `34.71` **BEFORE** you do any "math" on that number, or don't allow oddball numeric representations to be entered into your field.

Comment: So there is not a way to fill in 34,71 and actually save and show 34,71?

Comment: sure, just don't do any math on that text... it is text, not a number. if you force PHP to treat it as a number, then you're going to get corrupted values when PHP truncates anything that ISN'T a number.

Comment: Oke I understand. is there a way to fill in 34,71 then convert that to 34.71 do the math and then go to comma again?

Comment: for form->php, just do a simple string replacement: `,` -> `.`. For php->form, use [number_format()](http://php.net/number_format)